# Set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value in strapi

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, strapi, current-time

I am using MySql in one of my project where backend is implemented using java and now I want to convert it to strapi project.

I have used some date field in database table and its default value is set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

But I can not find any workaround to set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value in strapi date fields.

I am happy to continue with either strapi v3 or v4.

Is it even possible?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The only option I could think of is using [lifecycle hooks](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/models.html#lifecycle-hooks) in which you could set this date on creation. Probably not exactly what you are asking, but maybe this solution will suffice.